# Difference between initWithData and initWithBytes of NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, byte, nsdata

I'm confused with the use of the following methods of `NSString`

1. `initWithData:encoding:`

   > Returns an NSString object initialized by converting given data into
   >   Unicode characters using a given encoding.
2. `initWithBytes:length:encoding:`

   > Returns an initialized NSString object containing a given number of bytes from a given  buffer of bytes interpreted in a given encoding.

And their usage is like:

```
NSMutableData *someData = //some data;
NSString *someString = nil;
```

- `someString= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
- `someString=[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[someData mutableBytes] length:[someData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

`NSData` class is a wrapper for **byte buffers**, then what is the difference between these similiar methods. Please help me to understand the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you may have some raw bytes not already wrapped in an `NSData` object. In that case you can use `initWithBytes:length:encoding:` without having to wrap it first.